# Symfony ICU Issue, routes using locale different than EN will fail

Tags: symfony, icu

After installing Yosemite and a new version of MAMP 
and when I'm trying to execute

> domain/app_dev.php/es/venues/3/show

This route is rendering a form containing a language type field, so it's requiring ICU.
being 'es' the locale i get errors. If I changed it to 'en' there's no problem.

The errors are:

> [1/2] ResourceBundleNotFoundException: The resource bundle
>   "/Users/a77/Documents/DEV/UVox
>   Com/vendor/symfony/icu/Symfony/Component/Icu/Resources/data/lang/root.php"
>   does not exist.
>
> [2/2] Couldn't read the indices [Languages] from
>   "/Users/a77/Documents/DEV/UVox
>   Com/vendor/symfony/icu/Symfony/Component/Icu/Resources/data/lang/es.res".
>   The indices also couldn't be found in the fallback locale(s)
>   "root.res".

My symfony version is 2.5, I'm running the  MAMP PHP 5.5.10. 
I updated dependencies via composer, including  "symfony/intl": "*",

I have followed several webs in order to install icu and intl via pecl.  But still get the error. I don't know how to check if the installations or the configs are ok. Maybe you can let me know how to test both via terminal and let you know what is the result...

Comment: What shows you `php -i | grep icu`?

Comment: Configure Command =>  '/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-93~55/Objects/php/configure'  '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--sysconfdir=/private/etc' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--enable-cli' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/Library/Server/Web/Config/php' '

Comment: '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--disable-cgi' '--with-curl=/usr' '--enable-dba' '--with-ndbm=/usr' '--enable-exif' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-ftp' '--with-png-dir=no' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-93~55/Root/usr/local' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-icu-dir=/usr' '--with-ldap=/usr' '--with-ldap-sasl=/usr' '--with-libedit=/usr' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--without-pear' '

Comment: '--with-pear=no' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-readline=/usr' '--enable-shmop' '--with-snmp=/usr' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--with-tidy' '--enable-wddx' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-zip' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved updgrading to Symfony 2.5.6

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to get resources only for language `es`. But now (from the moment of importing to Symfony icu data) you need to get language resources via language and country codes `es_ES`.

Comment: How can I achieve this w/o changing the url?

Comment: You can just convert every `es` parameter into `es_ES` when creating a new Translator.

Comment: There's no problem when I'm using the translator component. The problem comes when I'm adding a language type to a form. And it fails if I set no params or if I set a choices including 'es' or 'es_ES'.

Comment: I forgot to see your comments. You have no installed intl extension. Did you enable it in your php.ini after installation?

Comment: Yes  extension=intl.so  is at the end of the active php.ini

Comment: `php -i | grep intl` ?

Comment: No result given. Btw I'm using MAMP Pro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63478/discussion-between-michael-sivolobov-and-arcovoltaico).

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to just simply activate intl.so after the Yosemite update. I solved the issue installing intl.so following an excellent article by Danilo Braband http://dab.io/posts/getting-started-with-symfony-on-yosemite.html

Comment: Follow each step, including installing HomeBrew. After the last one I read /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/54.1: 242 files, 65M. But still I got the same problem when running my MAMP Pro dev symfony project...